# Xcode Trigger function and action together

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

i wish that on button click it will switch screen in story board and also trigger function. But the problem is if the button have segue and function only the segue triggered but the function don`t, if i remove the segue the function work OK. Here is my print screen for better understanding, on the right you can see function and action triggers.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call your function from `prepareForSegue:`.

Comment: Thanks! I probably had brain freeze... It was just as simple as you said.